# Mysql/PHP error: not displaying $username

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, mysqli

Hello Everyone I figured out my problem with my `php SQL` not updating the table "as_users" it is because it cannot get `$username`.

The problem is I do not know how to make it detect `$username` , it already detects it and displays it as html but when it is trying to do the `mysql` it cannot get `$username` I do not know why, can anyone explain or help me solving this problem ?It would be greatly appreciated.

**MORE INFO**: the emails do not get `$username` neither does `mysql` but the echo at the bottom displays the correct username.

```
<?php
//
//  
//  
//  IPN system $username cannot be found in mysqli/emails but can be in html
//
//
// The way to inform the user about the status of your payment

require_once "paypal_config.php";
include 'templates/header.php';
$userDetails = $user->getDetails();
$user = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `as_users`");
$username =$userInfo['username'];

//
// FUNCTIONS
//
// Basic function for email notification 
function send_mail($message,$email)
{
    $subject=   "New Payment";
    $sender=    "Paypal Payment $company";

    $header .=  "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
    $header .=  "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n"; 
    $header .=  "From: ".$sender."<".$email.">\n";
    $header .=  "Return-path: ". $refers."\n";
    $header .=  "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion()."\n";
    $message .= "<br>";

    foreach($_POST as $name=>$value)
            {
            $message .= $name.": ".$value."<br>";
            }

    mail($email, $subject, $message, $header); 

}


// Examines all the IPN and turns it into a string
function Array2Str($kvsep, $entrysep, $a)
{
    $str = "";
    foreach ($a as $k=>$v)
    {$str .= "{$k}{$kvsep}{$v}{$entrysep}";}
    return $str;
}


//
// Verifying paypal message - Using POST vars rm=2 in html form 
//
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
$fullipnA = array();

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $fullipnA[$key] = $value; 
    $encodedvalue = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$encodedvalue";
}
$fullipn = Array2Str(" : ", "\n", $fullipnA);

    $url ='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';  

$curl_result=$curl_err='';
$fp = curl_init();
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-Length: " . strlen($req)));
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0); 
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

$response = curl_exec($fp);
$curl_err = curl_error($fp);
curl_close($fp);


// Vars received by Paypal
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
if (strcmp ($response, "VERIFIED") == 0)        
{
    // Check the status of the order
    if ($payment_status != "Completed")
    {       
        send_mail("The payment was not accepted by paypal - Payment Status: $payment_status", $email);

        exit;
    }
    // all good so far, the transaction has been confirmed so I can do all -> Update DB, stock, credit computations, activate accounts etc etc

    // Vars received by Paypal
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
    $pending_reason = $_POST['pending_reason'];
    $payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
    $custom = $_POST['custom'];
    $invoice =$_POST['invoice'];
    // Buyer information
    $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
    $address_name=$_POST['address_name'];
    $address_country=$_POST['address_country'];
    $address_country_code=$_POST['address_country_code'];
    $address_zip=$_POST['address_zip'];
    $address_state=$_POST['address_state'];
    $address_city=$_POST['address_city'];
    $address_street=$_POST['address_street'];
    if ($paypal_mysql) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli('****', '**', '***', '**');
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `as_users` SET paid='1', reg_date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, end_date=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
        send_mail("Tried to SQL  table with: $username", $email);
    }
    send_mail("New payment was successfully recieved from $payer_email username: $username1", $email);
  }else{    
     //the transaction is invalid I can NOT charge the client. 
     send_mail("$username Invalid payment - $fullipn", $email);

}
?>
<li>User: <?php echo $username ?> </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have invalid variable name `$username1` (I guess it should be `$username`):

```
send_mail("New payment was successfully recieved from $payer_email username: $username1", $email);
```

It also not clear where `$paypal_mysql` is coming from. I imagine if it is not set, then you'll miss your saving code.

Comment: it is set in paypal config and it is = TRUE; and I set that as username1 just to test another $username variable, even if I remove $paypal_mysql if method it doesn't work the problem is it's not getting $username

Comment: It's not clear where `$userInfo` value is coming from at `$username = $userInfo['username'];`?

Comment: that comes from include 'templates/header.php'; and it works with html, like it displays username on html

Comment: If username is printed at `<li>User: <?php echo $username ?> </li>`, then I don't see how value can be "lost" during code flow. Most likely one of the conditions is not working. Try to add few `var_dump($username)` in critical places. Also check that `mysqli` functions are returning TRUE value. Try to run UPDATE query directly in mysql. If this doesn't work, then create smallest possible script with all modules embedded, etc. without *any* `include` or `require`. And post it here, so everyone will be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ivan here is the problem if I put this code 
       $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `as_users` SET paid='1', reg_date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, end_date=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute(); at the top underneath the $username the mysqli works any explanation for that?

Comment: This is good. Now you know that the problem is happening somewhere between `$username =$userInfo['username'];` and `if ($paypal_mysql) {`. Try to move this block *before* `if ($paypal_mysql) {`, then before `if ($payment_status != "Completed")`, then before `if (strcmp ($response, "VERIFIED") == 0)`. Depending on results you'll get better idea about which code is causing issue.

Comment: when you say move the "block" what are you referring to?

Comment: The code you've moved previously: `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE as_users SET paid='1', reg_date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, end_date=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE username = ?"); $stmt->bind_param('s', $username); $stmt->execute();`

Comment: Ivan now I know that my $username method becomes NULL after ($response, "VERIFIED") == 0), but how could this occur?Because all the variables that it gets from paypal works and it emails me all the variables from paypal any idea why my $username breaks after ($response, "VERIFIED") == 0)?

Comment: So, you're saying that "UPDATE" code works if you put it *before* `if (strcmp ($response, "VERIFIED") == 0)`, but it doesn't work if you put it *after* `if (strcmp ($response, "VERIFIED") == 0)`? Can you print value like this `var_dump($username); if (strcmp ($response, "VERIFIED") == 0) { var_dump($username);`?

Comment: Yes that is correct the update code works if I put it before verified or if I put it under
 }else{  
    //the transaction is invalid I can NOT charge the client. 
  send_mail("Invalid payment - $fullipn", $email);

Comment: I dumped the username and it returned as NULL but it works this is so confusing any way you can add me on skype- legendfinalhero, I will pay please I have been stuck on this for hours/days